# How to write regular expression to get everything within a quote

Tags: python, regex

Does anyone know how to a regular expression in python to get everything in between a quotation marks?

For example, text: "some text here".... text: "more text in here!"... text:"and some numbers - 2343- here too"

The text are of different length, and some contain punctuation and numbers as well. How do I write a regular expression to extract all the information?

what I would like to see in the compiler:

some text here
more text in here
and some numbers - 2343 - here too

Answer (score 7):

This should work for you:

```
"(.*?)"
```

Placing a `?` after the `*` will restrict it to match as little as possible, so it doesn't consume any quote marks.

```
>>> r = '"(.*?)"'
>>> s =  'text: "some text here".... text: "more text in here!"... text:"and some numbers - 2343- here too"'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r, s)
['some text here', 'more text in here!', 'and some numbers - 2343- here too']
```

Answer (score 7):

Try `"[^"]*"`  that is, `"` followed by zero or more items that aren't `"`, followe by `"`.
So:

```
pat = re.compile(r'"[^"]*"').
```

Comment: I like Karl's answer better than mine.  Thanks, Karl

Answer (score 1):

If the quoted sub-strings to be matched do NOT contain escaped characters, then both Karl Barker's and Pierce's answers will both match correctly. However, of the two, Pierce's expression is more efficient:

```py
reobj = re.compile(r"""
    # Match double quoted substring (no escaped chars).
    "                   # Match opening quote.
    (                   # $1: Quoted substring contents.
      [^"]*             # Zero or more non-".
    )                   # End $1: Quoted substring contents.
    "                   # Match closing quote.
    """, re.VERBOSE)
```

But if the quoted sub-string to be matched DOES contain escaped characters, (e.g. "She said: \"Hi\" to me.\n"), then you'll need a different expression:

```py
reobj = re.compile(r"""
    # Match double quoted substring (allow escaped chars).
    "                   # Match opening quote.
    (                   # $1: Quoted substring contents.
      [^"\\]*           # {normal} Zero or more non-", non-\.
      (?:               # Begin {(special normal*)*} construct.
        \\.             # {special} Escaped anything.
        [^"\\]*         # more {normal} Zero or more non-", non-\.
      )*                # End {(special normal*)*} construct.
    )                   # End $1: Quoted substring contents.
    "                   # Match closing quote.
    """, re.DOTALL | re.VERBOSE)
```

There are several expressions I'm aware of that will do the trick, but the one above (taken from  [MRE3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124)) is the most efficient of the bunch. See [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5696141/433790) where these various, functionally identical expressions are compared.