# regex to find all functions being called

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-match-all

I'm trying to build a regex to find all function calls inside a string. For example:

```
 No No       No       No         Yes       Yes        No DOT YES   NO    YES
 |  |        |        |           |         |         |   |   |     |      |
(1, 2, 3 * (1/4), 'somestr()', findme(), andme ( ), 'and' . me(), NTME, me(0) )
```

---

```
   No        No          No
   |         |           |
(CONST, 'some"q()', "nop\"no()")
```

The strings will always be in the format of a parameter list eq => `(a,b,c...)`

Note that in the case of `'and' . me()` it should only match the `me()` part

So far I was able to use [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5696141/465546) to create a regex that matches anything *inside* quotes:

```
'/' . 
    '(?:\'[^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*)*\')' .      // single quoted string
        '|' .                                       //   or
    '(?:"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*")' .          // double quoted string
'/s';
```

What I need is a regex that will match anything **not** in the above regex that is a `\w\s*\(`

To clarify I'm trying to match anything that has a Yes above it

How would I go about writing a regex like that?

Comment: Is your source string always a contained list of expressions? If you intend to run this against a whole PHP script, clearly the [tokenizer](http://php.net/tokenizer) is less work. Or consider the [PHP_Parser](http://www.google.com/search?q=PHP_Parser)

Comment: [An example](https://github.com/digitalnature/php-ref/blob/master/ref.php#L460) that you could adapt, using the tokenizer (will get you all arguments passed to the function, as an array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comments above about tokenizers, but here is how you might achieve this with regex.

First, php allows lookarounds, so you could just match `\w\s*\(` that is *not preceded by* a ' or ":

```
(?<!["'])\b\w+\s*\(
```

(see the [interactive regexr here](http://regexr.com?33tje))

The `(?<!["'])` says "not preceded by a `"` or `'`".
The `\b` means that we should match whole function names instead of starting in the middle.

To convert this to php syntax I think you double up backslashes (the extra-backslash-escaping always confuses me):

```
'/(?<!["\'])\\b(\\w+)\\s*\\(/s'
```

Also, note that since `\w` is `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`, this would match `2()`. It would also match the `no` in `"asdf no()"` which is inside quotes, as there is no `'` or `"` immediately preceding the `no`.

In that case, you could additionally specify that there be no quotes *after* the closing bracket like so:

```
(?<!["'])\b\w+\s*\([^)]+\)(?!'")
```

where the `(?!'")` says "not followed by `'` or `"`".

This introduces a new set of problems, for example if your function calls have nested brackets in them (`matchme('(asdf)')` would not match). You can continue tweaking and tweaking the regex for cases like these but there is always something that will break the regex and in the end, it's **easier to use a tokenizer or parser**.