# How to close a string the way that bash does in php CLI or suppress error output?

Tags: php, bash, command-line-interface, shell-exec, suppress

If you create a simple php script with this code:

```
shell_exec('"');
```

And run it with:

```
php myscript.php
```

It gives the following error in bash on my Mac:

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I've tried everything I can think of:

```
ob_start();
@shell_exec('"');
ob_end_clean();

@shell_exec('" 2> /dev/null');
```

But no matter what I try, I can't suppress the message.  The problem is that I'm creating a unit test to stress test $argc, $argv and the getopt() command for a general purpose tool, and I need to call the script hundreds of times with various inputs containing random characters like '"=: etc.

So I need to be able to either suppress the error output, or detect imbalanced quotes and append either a ' or " to the end of the string.  I found this regex to detect single and double quoted strings:

[PHP: Regex to ignore escaped quotes within quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695240/php-regex-to-ignore-escaped-quotes-within-quotes)

But I'm having trouble visualizing how to do this for a general bash command that has a mix of quoted and unquoted arguments.  Is there a built-in command that would tell me if the string is acceptable without throwing an error?  Then I could try appending either "'" or '"' and I'm fairly certain that one of them would close the string.  I'm only concerned with preventing the error message for now, because I'm just throwing random input at the script at this point.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already tried `escapeshellarg`?

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to do because " 2> /dev/null is not a valid bash command.

Comment: Ya to both: I can't use escapeshellarg() because I'm trying to pass a malformed query to the CLI to stress test getopt().  Also, I was representing the random command string I was passing as a double quote, I should have been more specific (it's a command with a mix of chars afterwards).

Comment: To anyone still reading this question, I realized that I still don't have a regex or way to validate the string I pass to shell_exec().  This makes it difficult to spawn processes in the background, because I don't know in advance if they will fail while parsing the arguments, especially if I close STDERR.  It seems that php has no way to redirect STDERR to a variable instead of the output, I could be wrong though.  Perhaps I awarded the answer too quickly, but, it was a viable solution to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child shell process is writing the error message to STDERR, which it inherited from the parent PHP process.  You could close the parent's STDERR file handle in the PHP script before running shell_exec().

```
<?php
fclose (STDERR);
shell_exec('"');
```