# Get html or text from inside quotes including escape quotes with RegEx

Tags: php, regex, parsing, lexer

What I want to do is to get the attribute value from a simple text I'm parsing. I want to be able to contain HTML as well inside the quotes, so that's what got me stalling right now.

```
$line = 'attribute = "<p class=\"qwerty\">Hello World</p>" attribute2 = "value2"'
```

I've gotten to the point (substring) where I'm getting the value

```
$line = '"<p class=\"qwerty\">Hello World</p>" attribute2 = "value2"'
```

My current regex works if there are no escaped quotes inside the text. However, when I try to escape the HTML quotes, it doesn't work at all. Also, using .* is going to the end of the second attribute.

What I'm trying to obtain from the string above is

```
$result = '<p class=\"qwerty\">Hello World</p>'
```

This is how far I've gotten with my trial and error regex-ing.

```
$value_regex = "/^\"(.+?)\"/"

if (preg_match($value_regex, $line, $matches)) 
     $result = $matches[1];
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: why not just use an HTML parser for this task

Comment: I'm currently learning how to create a lexer and parser in php. It's something I'm currently learning and I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use negative lookbehind to avoid matching escaped quotes:

```
(?<!\\)"(.+?)(?<!\\)"
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dH3xY0/2)

Here `(?<!\\)` is **negative lookbehind** that will avoid matching `\"`.

However I would caution you on using regex to parse HTML, better to use DOM for that.

---

**PHP Code:**

```
$value_regex = '~(?<!\\\\)"(.+?)(?<!\\\\)"~';
if (preg_match($value_regex, $line, $matches)) 
     $result = $matches[1];
```

Comment: Can you update your answer to set the regex to a variable? I'm getting an error and I think I might've escaped the wrong way. Thank you!

Comment: This solution does not work reliably. What if the last char in the string is an escaped escape? e.g. `'stuff "string\\" string'`. Note also that this question has been asked and answered before see: [PHP: Regex to ignore escaped quotes within quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5696141/433790)

Comment: For those cases regex would be: `(?<!(?<!\\)\\)"(.+?)(?<!(?<!\\)\\)"` as in [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/dH3xY0/3)

Comment: @ridgerunner I didn't consider the case you mentioned. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @anubhava Once again, thank you! Really happy for the help! I've managed to get my lexer to be completely working! :)