# Group quotes and ignore escaped quotes

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently using `(['\"])(?:\\1|.*?\\1)` to capture group of quotes.

```
Text: "Hello", is it 'me youre looking for'?
# result: "Hello" (\1) and 'me youre looking for' (\2)
```

Additionally I want it to ignore escaped quotes inside those groups (or globally, also fine).

```
Text: "Hello", is it 'me you\'re looking for'?
# result: "Hello" (\1) and 'me you\'re looking for' (\2)
```

Using python. I'm aware that [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695240/php-regex-to-ignore-escaped-quotes-within-quotes) is somewhat similar. However, I was unable to apply it to my existing regex.

Thanks, regex freaks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a pattern:

```
(['"])(?:\\.|.)*?\1
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aE4lH7/1)

Everyting lies in the `(?:\\.|.)` bit:

- either match an escaped character: `\\.` - this handles both `\"` and `\\`
- or any other (read: unescaped) character: `.` - you could also use `[^\\]` here.

Since the regex engine tries alternations from left to right, it'll try matching an escaped character first.

By the way, in your pattern, `\1|.*?\1` was redundant, you could just have written `.*?\1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below regex.

```
(?<!\\)(['"])(?:\\\1|(?!\1).)*\1
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aE4lH7/3)

- `(?<!\\)` negative lookbehind which asserts that the match won't be preceeded by a backslash character.
- `(['"])` this would capture unescaped single or double quotes.
- `(?:\\\1|(?!\1).)*` , `\\\1` this would match an escaped `'` or `"` quotes based on the captured character or any character but not of the captured character, zero or more times.
- `\1` refers the first captured character.

In python you need to alter the `re.findall` function like below.

```
>>> def match(s):
        for i in re.findall(r'''(?<!\\)((['"])(?:\\\2|(?!\2).)*\2)''', s):
            print(i[0])


>>> match(r""""Hello", is it 'me you\'re looking for'""")
"Hello"
'me you\'re looking for'
>>> match(r"""Hello\", is it 'me you\'re looking for'""")
'me you\'re looking for'
>>>
```