# Python regular expression on single quoted string with escaped single quotes

Tags: python, regex, ply

Suppose that we have some input like this (it's an example, no matter if it makes sense or not):

```
data = "(((column_1 + 7.45) * 3) <>    column_2 - ('string\'1' / 2))"
```

Well, I need to match a string, that starts and ends with `'` and may contain escaped single quotes as example above, using Python re module. So the result should be `string\'1`. How can we achieve it?

**EDIT:** I am using the PLY library and the usage should be

```
def t_leftOperand_arithmetic_rightOperand_STRING(self, t):
    r'<regex>'
    t.lexer.pop_state()
    return t
```

Comment: Your `\ ` will not survive (try printing `data`), you need a raw string.

Comment: Asked and answered already - [PHP: Regex to ignore escaped quotes within quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5696141/433790).

Comment: Check: http://www.regexr.com/ and http://www.txt2re.com/?

Comment: @cdarke You're right! `data = '(((column_1 + 7.45) * 3) <>    column2 - (\'string\\\'1\' / 2) +  \'14.02.2016\')'` like this?

Comment: OR use a raw string, that is `r" .... "`  that will preserve backslashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to account for the escape being escaped as well.

For that, you'd need `'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'`

---

Input

```
'''Set 1 - this
is another
mul\'tiline
string'''
'''Set 2 - this
is' a\\nother
mul\'''tiline
st''ring'''
```

[Benchmark:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
Regex1:   '[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   400  /  400     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   9
Elapsed Time:    5.00 s,   4995.27 ms,   4995267 µs


Regex2:   '(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'
Options:  < s >
Completed iterations:   400  /  400     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   9
Elapsed Time:    7.00 s,   7000.68 ms,   7000680 µs
```

Additional regex (For a test only. As @ridgerunner says this *could* cause a backtracking problem)

```
Regex2:   '(?:[^'\\]+|\\.)*'
Options:  < s >
Completed iterations:   400  /  400     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   9
Elapsed Time:    5.45 s,   5449.72 ms,   5449716 µs
```

Comment: Or just `'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'` I think.

Comment: @Zasta - I stay away from using that form. One reason is its much slower. The other reason is it might run into stack overflow if embedded into a heavy expression. I'll throw up a benchmark.

Comment: Fair enough - but unless there are specific performance considerations, I try to go for the most readable (although the 40% difference here is not small). Any specific reason for the classes instead of a dot, other than matching a newline (for which DOTALL could be set if required)?

Comment: And since you're benching anyway, does `'(?:[^'\\]*|\\.)*'` help matters any?

Comment: Couple of answers. First off, you'd never want to leave something as optional in an optionally quantified group, ie. like this '(?:`[^'\\]*`|\\.)*' something like `'(?:[^'\\]+|\\.)*'` is ok. Secondly, the more escaped items in a string will exponentially slow down the alternation method, compared to the unrolled-loop method. Third, the dot `.` will match tabs, form feed and other control characters, so why exclude a newline. (?s) is acceptable (I added it in the benchmark). And, I'll post `'(?:[^'\\]+|\\.)*'` results as well.

Comment: @Zastai - No. The expression `'(?:[^'\\]*|\\.)*'` is subject to catastrophic backtracking for cases where the string does not match. BTW, this question gets asked a lot - e.g. [PHP: Regex to ignore escaped quotes within quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5696141/433790)

Comment: @sin - `'(?:[^'\\]+|\\.)*'` suffers the same catastrophic backtracking problem when faced with a non-matching string.

Comment: Yep, it does. That's why I always leave alternations unquantified. Still, this `'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'` is subject to stack overflow in some situations.