# Splitting text into an associative array

Tags: php, regex

Let's say, I have this text:

```
add name=100YER on-login=":do {:put \"a\";} on-error={};" rate-limit=256k/512k
```

I want to extract an array with key and value, eg:

```json
{
    "name": "100YER",
    "on-login": ":do {:put \"a\";} on-error={};"
    "rate-limit": "256k/512k"
}
```

How to do that if there is another value contains a `=` character?

I used this regex to split it by `=`, but the problem is in on-login value.

```php
if (preg_match_all('/[^=]+/i', $response, $MATCHES) ){
    //
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use 2 capturing groups with a branch reset group:

```
(\w+(?:-\w+)*)=(?|"((?:[^"]+|(?<=\\)")++)"|([^"\s]+))
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\w+(?:-\w+)*` Match 1+ word chars optionally followed by a `-` and 1+ word chars
- `)` Close group 1
- `=` Match literally
- `(?|` Branch reset group

  - `"(` Match `"` and start **group 2**

    - `(?:[^"]+|(?<=\\)")++` Match any char except `"` or `\"`
  - `)"` Close group 2 and match `"`
  - `|` Or
  - `([^"\s]+)` Capture **group 3**, match any char except `"` or a whitespace char
- `)` Close branch reset group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/52tkug/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/ht0CG)

For example

```
$re = '/(\w+(?:-\w+)*)=(?|"((?:[^"]+|(?<=\\\\)")++)"|([^"\s]+))/';
$str = 'add name=100YER on-login=":do {:put \\"a\\";} on-error={};" rate-limit=256k/512k';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [name] => 100YER
    [on-login] => :do {:put \"a\";} on-error={};
    [rate-limit] => 256k/512k
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To improve upon @Thefourthbird's pattern, use the wisdom from the "best" technique at [PHP: Regex to ignore escaped quotes within quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5696141/2943403).  Not only does this improve pattern efficiency in terms of step count, it also more accurately differentiates backslashes that are used literally versus used for escaping.

Otherwise, I completely concur that a branch reset is most suitable for keeping the targeted substrings in consistent columns of `preg_match_all()`'s output array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/huqNL))

```
$string = <<<MIKROTIK
add name=100YER on-login=":do {:put \"a\";} on-error={};" rate-limit=256k/512k
MIKROTIK;

var_export(
    preg_match_all(
        '~(\w+(?:-\w+)*)=(?|"([^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*)"|([^" ]+))~',
        $string,
        $out
    )
    ? array_combine($out[1], $out[2])
    : []
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'name' => '100YER',
  'on-login' => ':do {:put \\"a\\";} on-error={};',
  'rate-limit' => '256k/512k',
)
```