# Parse xpath expression into file path

Tags: c#, xpath, cognos-bi

For whatever stupid reason, the API I'm querying returns file paths as XPath. I'm trying to figure out a way to parse it back into a file path. So for example,

```xml
/content/folder[@name='Dropbox']
----> content/Dropbox

/content/folder[@name='whatever']/folder[@name='something else']/report[@name='why']
----> content/whatever/something else/why

/content/folder[@name='A/B']
----> content/A/B
```

The best idea I have right now is to split the xpath by / delimiters and then comprehend the individual tags, but that will break on test case 3 above. Alternatively, I could just write a pushdown automata and do it myself. Is there an xpath reverse parser that I can use to process these strings into something intelligent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps use a regular expression find and replace, look for substrings matching this regular expression:

```
[^\/]*\[@name='([^']+)']
```

... and replace each match with the captured group.
e.g. https://regex101.com/r/n42SqR/1

Comment: I don't know C#, but I think this is the functionality I'm thinking of: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, XPath allows you to have either single-quoted or double-quoted strings, and you can escape characters from within the string. Building off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5696141/8954291), I created the following regex:

```
/\w+\[@name=(?:""(?<name>[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*)""|'(?<name>[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)')\]
```

And a breakdown:

```
/\w+\[@name=                            # Match the xpath preamble for the section.
(?:                                     # Anonymous group
    "(?<name>[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"   # Match a double-quoted string with escapes. Save it to the <name> capture group.
   |'(?<name>[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'   # OR match a single-quoted string with escape. Save it to the <name> capture group.
)\]                                     # End the anonymous group and match a literal ]
```