# Regex to remove all comments from CSS file in Sublime Text 2

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am in need of a Sublime Text 2 friendly regex that would allow me to search for all comments within a file.

The comments are all following this basic structure `/* <anything> */`

Thanks for taking the time to help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [using regex to remove comments from source files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319019/using-regex-to-remove-comments-from-source-files)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
\/\*.+?\*\/
```

I'm not super-familiar with Sublime Text, but this would work in Notepad++, and I believe the regex implementation is basically the same. If I'm wrong, feel free to let me know.

**Edit:** Per CAustin's helpful tip, you can also just do this (without the escaping of the forward slashes):

```
/\*.+?\*/
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the forward slashes, so this would work too:
`/\*.+?\*/`

Comment: @CAustin Good to know; I will tweak accordingly.

Comment: `\/\*[\s\S]+?\*\/` also captures multiline comments. @CAustin mentioned it in the comments of another answer, but I spent some minutes on regexr.com to figure it out because I didn't look further than the accepted answer. To save anyone from the same fate, I thought I'd double post that here -.-

Answer (score 17):

Search for:

```
(?s)/\*.*?\*/
```

This allows you to match comments that spreads over multiple lines.

The `(?s)` turns on "single line" mode, which makes `.` matches any character without exception (by default, `.` excludes line separators).

This assumes that there is no `/*` or `*/` inside a string literal.

Or if you want a bullet-proof solution, you may want to take a look at this question:

[Can we make use of syntax highlighting feature to remove all comments from a source file in SublimeText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286879/how-to-remove-all-comments-from-a-source-file-in-sublimetext)

Comment: For a multiline match, this would be simpler:
`/\*[\s\S]+?\*/`

Comment: @CAustin Note: If you use `calc()` and multiply inside or you're using sass and multiply in it or have comments that include `*` that solution doesn't work. At least didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is better:

```
\/\*[^(?:\*\/)]*\*\/
```