# Regex match unescaped quotes

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm looking for a regex that matches unescaped quotes in an arbitrary string, but not quotes that are already escaped so I can escape the unescaped quotes. I tried to modify any similar solutions I found but nothing captured exactly what I need.

The regex should

```
abc"asd # match
abc\"asd # not match
abc\\"asd # match
abc\\\"asd # not match
abc\\\\"asd # match
```

so basically match any quotes preceded by an even number of backslashes (including zero) but not match any quotes preceded by an odd number of backslashes.

Can anyone help?

PS: I want to do this in ruby

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use this:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\K"
```

`(?<!\\)` checks there is no backslash before (negative lookbehind)

`(?:\\{2})*` matches all even numbers of backslashes

`\K` removes all on the left from the match result (the backslashes here)

Comment: An explanation of what each part does would probably be helpful for OP and future readers.

Answer (score -3):

It seems that you may be looking for something like this:

```
(\\\\)*"
```

Comment: This will match on any `"`, as the backslashes are completely optional. So the `"` in `not\"thisone` will match.