# Regex non-escaped quotation marks

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, given:

`hello"there\"boo\\\\"elephant`

In general, I would like to match the first and 3rd quotes, but not the middle, as the middle one is escaped. This works with `(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*"` ([Regex match unescaped quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24209711/regex-match-unescaped-quotes)); however, that regex includes the look-behind (e.g. 2 slashes) in the captured group. Is there a way to make the look-behind non-capturing.

If relevant, I'll be using javascript, so the `\K` that the other stackoverflow post I linked uses doesn't seem to work.

edit, to clarify, I don't want to replace the double quotes, I simply want to match them. My use case specifically is to find the index, but I can do that with the existing query, using something like `match.index + match[0].length - 1`, but I find that ugly and I wanted to better understand regex, so I was hoping there was a simpler regex to find the unescaped quote without capturing anything prior to it.

Comment: It is still the same approach, use [`/((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\{2})*)"/`](https://regex101.com/r/VCt1Ye/2). You rarely can't do without `\K` since you may work around it using capturing groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you want to replace those unescaped quotes and to do that you do not need `\K` nor lookbehinds. Replace the lookbehind with a corresponding alternation group and capture what you need to restore with a capturing group and use a replacement backreference.

```
s.replace(/((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\{2})*)"/g, "$1'")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VCt1Ye/2).

**Details**

- `((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\{2})*)` - Group 1 (its value can be accessed with `$1` placeholder from the replacement pattern):

  - `(?:^|[^\\])` - either start of the string or any char other than `\`
  - `(?:\\{2})*` - 0+ occurrences of double backslash
- `"` - a double quote.

JS demo:

```js
var rx = /((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\{2})*)"/g;
var s = "hello\"there\\\"boo\\\\\\\\\"elephant";
console.log("String:", s);
console.log("Result:", s.replace(rx, "$1'"));
```