# javascript regex match including non-capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying one of the comments from my earlier stackoverflow question ([Regex non-escaped quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261853/regex-non-escaped-quotation-marks/50262225#50262225)) led to a new question:

```
var string = 'hello"ther';
string.match(/(?:[^\\])"/);
// ["o"", index: 4, input: "hello"ther", groups: undefined]
```

The match includes the `o` before the `"`, even though the group has the `?:` which I thought made it non-capturing.

https://regex101.com/r/VCt1Ye/5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *match* includes the entire string that matches the RegExp. A *non-capturing group* just means that it won't be recognized as a group, which would show up in the `groups` section, but it will still appear in the matched string.

In other words, here is what you would get with capturing groups:

```
var string = 'hello"ther';
console.log(string.match(/([^\\])"/));
// ["o\"","o"]
```

Here, the first element is the entire matched string (still the same, captured or uncaptured). It's just that it also captures the "o" as a separate group, which is not true for an uncapturing group.

---

It looks like you're trying to escape non-escaped matches. If you want to do that, you can do that like so (using *capturing groups*):

```
string = string.replace(/([^\\])(")/, '$1\\$2')
```

Where group 1 is `[^\\]` and group 2 is `"` by putting a slash in front of it.

---

Edit for clarification: The groups are numbered as follows:

- `matches[0]`: the entire matched group
- `matches[1]`: the first captured group
- `matches[2]`: the second captured group
- ...

An easy way to tell which group it is is to count opening capturing group parentheses before the group. For example, the group `($([\d,]+)` in the regex below:

```
/Total balance for (\w+): (($([\d,]+)\.(\d{2}))/
                   ^      ^^           ^
                   1      23           4
```

is `matches[3]` because it is the third opening parenthesis.

Comment: oh that makes sense. and do you happen to know how to find the indexes of the captured groups, rather than the indexes of the entire match?

Comment: @junvar The indeces are in order (`matches[0]` is the entire matched string, `matches[1]` is the first captured group, `matches[2]` is the second captured group, etc.) A simple tip is to count the number of opening parentheses before the group to get the group number. I'll add an example in my code.

Comment: @junvar If this answer helps you, make sure to accept it to show the community it helped!

Comment: @JonathanLam Can you please explain how I would solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55166587/295783) with `data.match(/(?::")(\w+)/g)` which did not work as expected?

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. Do you mean you only want to capture the two-letter code? If so, the `.match()` returns an array with the *complete* matches (with the `:"` included); I made [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/Lpncd64x/) to show how it can be done with lookbehinds (experimental) and by cutting out the first two characters of each match. It looks like you're already doing something similar to the latter in your answer.

Another option would be to use the `.exec()` function to iterate over the matches, and you could get the code using `match[1]`.

Comment: Hi, I want to NOT have to loop or use exec. I have written 3 regexes today and each time I just wanted an array of the captured group without the non captured

Comment: @mplungjan did you see the fiddle i posted? Neither method uses a loop. If that's not what you're asking, please ask a new question rather than asking here in the comments.

Comment: Right, I saw the code, so the lookbehind is what I wanted. The second version is similar to what I did with the replace

Comment: @mplungjan I'm glad you found what you were looking for. Unfortunately, [browser support is limited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Browser_compatibility), so iterating over the elements may still be the best way for now.