# MySQL only replace a single character if a pattern of characters is not there

Tags: mysql, parsing

I need to be able to replace a single character as long as it's not a specific combination of other characters. For example, if I find a single ' in my TEXT value, I need to escape it; but if it's already escaped (\') I need to ignore it.

There could also be more complex variations such as \"\ that I simply want to replace with -.

I also need to see if there are \" entries, but make sure they aren't already \\" (double escaped).

I'm guessing the solution is REGEXP_REPLACE, but I don't know how to properly tell it to NOT replace a matching pattern if another pattern exists...

Thanks!

Comment: You need a negative lookbehind, but MySQL's regexp syntax doesn't have this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24209711/regex-match-unescaped-quotes

Comment: That negative lookbehind reference above is exactly what I was looking for. Please post that as the answer and I will accept it. Thanks! (BTW might want to delete the above comment saying we can't do it LOL)

Comment: Are you sure it worked? I checked the MySQL documentation, didn't see any mention of lookarounds. Are you using MariaDB instead?

Comment: You are correct; it doesn't work with MySQL. *sigh* Any other recommended approaches?