# Python Regex: I want to remove newlines after every '%}' tag close except for content in between {% verbatim%} ... {% endverbatim %} tag

Tags: python, regex, string, algorithm

I am writing regular expression for removing newlines after every tag closing like "%}\n" for template strings. But it shouldn't remove when the content is in between the {% verbatim %}content{% endverbatim %} tag and also shouldn't remove newline after {% endverbatim %} if any present.

I tried this :

```
import re
def my_function(template_string):

    replacement_string = template_string
    found = re.search("{%\s*verbatim\s*%}(\s*.*\s*){%\s*endverbatim\s*%}", template_string, re.DOTALL)
    replacement_string = re.sub("%}\n","%}", replacement_string, re.DOTALL)
    replacement = "{%% verbatim %%}%s{%% endverbatim %%}" % found.group(1)
    pattern = re.compile("{%\s*verbatim\s*%}(\s*.*\s*){%\s*endverbatim\s*%}", re.DOTALL)
    result_string = pattern.sub(replacement, replacement_string)
    return result_string
```

I used this string to test this regex:

> "This is test string\n {% set var=2 %}\n  {% verbatim %}\n Inside
>   verbatim 1 {% set var2=4%}\n {% endverbatim %} {% set value=10%}\n {%
>   verbatim%} Inside verbatim 2 {% set new_val=13%}\n {% endverbatim %}\n
>   ..."

```
template_string = "This is test string\n {% set var=2 %}\n  {% verbatim %}\n Inside verbatim 1 {% set var2=4%}\n {% endverbatim %} {% set value=10%}\n {% verbatim%} Inside verbatim 2 {% set new_val=13%}\n {% endverbatim %}\n    ..."
my_function(template_string)
```

output of function above:

> 'This is test string\n {% set var=2 %}  {% verbatim %}\n Inside
>   verbatim 1 {% set var2=4%}\n {% endverbatim %} **{% set value=10%}\n** {%
>   verbatim%} Inside verbatim 2 {% set new_val=13%}\n **{% endverbatim %}**
>   ...'

Result I want:

> 'This is test string\n {% set var=2 %}  {% verbatim %}\n Inside 
>   verbatim 1 {% set var2=4%}\n {% endverbatim %} **{% set value=10%}** {% 
>   verbatim%} Inside verbatim 2 {% set new_val=13%}\n **{% endverbatim %}\n**
>   ...'

Comment: You can do that with lookaheads and lookbehinds

Comment: Check [this solution](https://ideone.com/XWUHqF) - does it work as expected?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks Solution is Working.

Comment: I will post with explanations then

Comment: Yeah Sure. Solution will helpful for others too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
import re

template_string = "This is test string\n {% set var=2 %}\n  {% verbatim %}\n Inside verbatim 1 {% set var2=4%}\n {% endverbatim %} {% set value=10%}\n {% verbatim%} Inside verbatim 2 {% set new_val=13%}\n {% endverbatim %}\n    ..."
x = re.sub(r"(?s)((?:{%\s*verbatim\s*%}.*?)?{%\s*endverbatim\s*%})|%}\n", lambda m: (m.group(1) if m.group(1) else "%}"), template_string)
print(x)
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/XWUHqF)

The `(?s)((?:{%\s*verbatim\s*%}.*?)?{%\s*endverbatim\s*%})|%}\n` regex matches:

- `(?s)` - enables the DOTALL mode (`.` matches a newline, too)
- `((?:{%\s*verbatim\s*%}.*?)?{%\s*endverbatim\s*%})` - Group 1 that matches

  - `(?:{%\s*verbatim\s*%}.*?)?` - one or zero occurrence (=optionally matches) `{%` followed with zero or more whitespace, then `verbatim`, then again zero or more whitespaces, followed with `%}`, then with zero or more characters but as few as possible up to the
  - `{%\s*endverbatim\s*%}` - `{% endverbatim %}` where the number of spaces inside can be any
- `|` - or...
- `%}\n` - a `%}`+newline

In the replacement part, a lamda is used to check if Group 1 is initialized (not None) because if it is not, a replacement pattern with `\1` will fail. Read [*Empty string instead of unmatched group error*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516298/empty-string-instead-of-unmatched-group-error/35516425#35516425) about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub` with a callback:

```
str = "This is test string\n {% set var=2 %}\n  {% verbatim %}\n Inside verbatim 1 {% set var2=4%}\n {% endverbatim %} {% set value=10%}\n {% verbatim%} Inside verbatim 2 {% set new_val=13%}\n {% endverbatim %}\n    ..."

def replcb(m):
    if m.group(1) == None:
        return "%}"
    else:
        return m.group(1)

print re.sub(r'({%\s*verbatim\s*%}[\s\S]*?{%\s*endverbatim\s*%})+|%}\n', replcb, str)
```

- This regex captures text between start and end tags in group #1 otherwise `%}\n` is matched without capturing group.
- `replcb` callback puts original captured string back in output if `m.group(1)` is a valid capture otherwise `\n` is replaced by `%}`.

**Output:**

```
This is test string
 {% set var=2 %}  {% verbatim %}
 Inside verbatim 1 {% set var2=4%}
 {% endverbatim %} {% set value=10%} {% verbatim%} Inside verbatim 2 {% set new_val=13%}
 {% endverbatim %}
    ...
```

[**Code Demo**](https://ideone.com/1wS3hY)

Comment: I want to remove newlines after every "%}" except the content in between {% verbatim%} {% endverbatim %} like: {% verbatim %} {% set var=10%}\n {% endverbatim %}. Newline doesn't get removed if "%}\n" appears in between {% verbatim %} {% endverbatim %}