# Python 2.7 Regex capture groups not working as predicted

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to pattern match and replace first person with second person with Python 2.7.

```
string = re.sub(r'(\W)I(\W)', '\g<1>you\g<2>',string)
string = re.sub(r'(\W)(me)(\W)', '\g<1>you\g<3>',string)
# but does NOT work
string = re.sub(r'(\W)I|(me)(\W)', '\g<1>you\g<3>',string)
```

I want to use the last regex, but somehow the capture groups are all messed up and even doing a \g<0> shows strange, irregular matches. I would think that capture group 3 would be the last word boundary, but it doesn't appear to be.

A sample sentence could be: `I like candy.`

I am not interested very much in the correctness of the replacement (me will never actually be selected since I goes first), but I don't know why the capture groups don't work as I would expect.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the Python version, BTW?

Comment: 2.7! I'll add to question.

Comment: Then, there are at least 2 issues with the 3rd pattern: wrong alternation boundaries, and non-participating group replacement. Don't you get `"unmatched group"` error?

Comment: I  do that's exactly it. Can you explain where I went wrong? :)

Comment: I can, I actually posted a long answer on that some time ago. See [*Empty string instead of unmatched group error*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516298/empty-string-instead-of-unmatched-group-error/35516425#35516425). If you still do not understand the root cause of your pattern issue, I will post an answer with explanations.

Comment: So, is that clear, or should I post an explanation?

Comment: I'm looking over your answer and will upvote the original thread. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you can, please upvote tomorrow :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Did I spotted **greedy** approach there ;-) ? P.S I was talking about cap of 200 :D IYKWIM !

Comment: @noob: I'd rather call it "optimization" approach :)

Answer (score 2):

Try with following regex.

**Regex:** `\b(I|me)\b`

**Explanation:**

- `\b` on both sides marks the word boundary.
- `(I|me)` matches either `I` OR `me`.

**Note:-** You can make it case insensitive using `i` flag.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gS0iA7/1)**

Comment: That's a way better answer. But do you know why the alternation seems to mess up the capture groups such that capture group 3 is no longer the one I would expect?

Comment: @NickAnderson: Since you used `\W` instead of word boundary it fails when `I` is at beginning of string. `(\W)(me)|I(\W)` will work too [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gS0iA7/2) but using word boundary is safer.

Comment: This is true. But comparing: string = re.sub(r'(\W)I|(me)(\W)', '\g<1>you\g<3>',string) and string = re.sub(r'(\W)(I|me)(\W)', '\g<1>you\g<3>',string), why are the groups different? Why does making the capture group nested under the alternation operator change how it works? I saw on the Python docs that you can use <2> to reference a nested level also, so does the meaning change based on context?

Comment: It's not about capturing groups. It will work even if you don't use one around `me`. You will have to use for grouping all alteration cases. `(I|me)`.

Comment: Thank you; that's very helpful!