# re.sub() documentation misunderstanding

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-3.5

I've just started learning regular expressions and the documentation for  `re.sub()` states:

> **Changed in version 3.5**: Unmatched groups are replaced with an empty
>   string.
>
> **Deprecated since version 3.5, will be removed in version 3.6**: Unknown
>   escapes consist of '\' and ASCII letter now raise a deprecation
>   warning and will be forbidden in Python 3.6.

Is re.sub() deprecated? What should I use then?

Comment: `re.sub` is **not** deprecated. Only specific replacement syntax is.

Comment: Are you getting a warning? Then please share the code that generated that warning. If not, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh, I misread this. Thanks. UPD. I don't get any warnings. Just started with docs.

Comment: I also tried it and did not get any warnings, but I added more examples to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand the documentation. The `re.sub()` function is **not deprecated**. The deprecation warning concerns *specific syntax*.

Earlier in the [`re.sub()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) you'll find this:

> Unknown escapes such as `\&` are left alone.

If you used and *unknown* escape with an *ASCII letter* the escape will no longer be ignored, you'll get a warning instead. This applies both to `re.sub()` replacement patterns *and* to the regular expression patterns. The same warning is placed in the section on regex pattern syntax.

The *Changed in version 3.5* line also concerns how `re.sub()` works. Rather than raise an exception when there is no matching group for a `\number` backreference, an empty string is inserted at that location.

Comment: A `\digit` is not an *escape sequence*, it is a backreference consisting of a literal ``\`` + a *number* (there are groups with IDs more than `9`).

Comment: @Wiktor: right, but it is still an escape sequence, one that *signifies* a backreference. Just like `\n` is an escape sequence that signifies a newline.

Comment: The `"\n"` is an escape sequence, but `r"\n"` is not an escape sequence, it is just a combination of ``\`` and `n` - I doubt any regex reference refers to them (and `\w`, `\d`, `\S`, etc.) as *escape sequences*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the regex engine still interprets the `\n` combination as special. You match a literal newline character with them.

Comment: Right, I just would not call it an escape sequence. Maybe I am too used to Microsoft terminology, where *escape sequence* refers to the string literals `\n`, `\r`, `\f`, `\a`, etc.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's a generic term that refers to the technique of flagging a change in meaning from the norm. They are not limited to string literals; switching terminal display modes and colours also use escape sequences, as do modem commands, and many more applications. See Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence

Answer (score 1):

The two entries are not related, and [**`re.sub`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) will  *not* be deprecated.

In Python version earlier than 3.5 `re.sub` failed if a backreference was used to a capturing group that did not participate in the match. See [**Empty string instead of unmatched group error**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35516425/3832970) SO question.

An [example](http://ideone.com/UVzXOQ) where the failure occurred:

```
import re
old = 'regexregex'
new = re.sub(r'regex(group)?regex', r'something\1something', old)
print(new) # => fail as there is no "group" in between "regex" and "regex" in "regexregex"
#    and Group 1 was not initialized with an empty string, i.e. remains null
```

As for the second one, it only says that there will be a warning (and later forbidden) if you use an *unknown for a regex engine* literal backslash followed with an ASCII character. The backslash was just ignored in them before, in Python 2.x through 3.5, `print(re.sub(r'\j', '', 'joy'))` [prints `oy`](http://ideone.com/gAF65v). So, these will be forbidden in Python 3.6.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Such a dumb question.

Comment: Well, the `re.sub` has been bugging for a long time, it is really a great change that came with Python 3.5. As for the unknown escape sequences, almost every Python regex SO (good) answer states that it is best practice to use *raw string literals* to define regex patterns. Now, it will be supported by these warnings.

Comment: Rather than describe the `re.sub` issue here, I hope the link to one of my answers will provide extensive reference on that issue that will remain in Python 2.x.

Comment: Python's too-forgiving string literals have always bugged me, but that's not what the warning is about.  It's referring to unknown *regex* escapes, like `\j`.  Python has always ignored the backslash, which is arguably wrong and definitely inconsistent with other flavors.

Comment: @AlanMoore: I see, I fixed that and updated with more illustrations.