# finding speical character smileys in a string

Tags: python, regex

Im currently writing a program in python where I have to figure out smileys like these `:)`, `:(`, `:-)`, `:-(` should be replace if it is followed by special characters and punctuation should be replaced in this pattern :
ex : `Hi, this is good :)#` should be replaced to `Hi, this is good :)`.

I have created regex pattern for sub it but couldn't enclose this smiley `:-)` in my `re.compile`.It is considering that as a range.

`re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9:):D)]+", " " , words)` this is working fine
I need to add `:-)` smiley to the regex.

Comment: Please [check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54997594/3832970), with demo and explanations. Note that the main problem with your pattern is that it contains a single character class where you added *a sequence of patterns* to be matched, but it does not work like that. You need a grouping here.

Comment: This is not a shameless promotion of my answer, but you could also check my answer to see if it worked for you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works perfectly ! but the same regex pattern in python 2 is throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the following pattern:

```
(:\)|:\(|:-\)|:-\()[^A-Za-z0-9]+
```

This matches *and* captures a smiley face, then matches any number of non alphanumeric characters immediately afterwards.  The replacement is just the captured smiley face, thereby removing the non alpha characters.

```
input = "Hi, this is good :)#"
output = re.sub(r"(:\)|:\(|:-\)|:-\()[^A-Za-z0-9]+", "\1" , input)
print(output)

Hi, this is good :)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `[^a-zA-Z0-9:):D)]` pattern is erronrous since it is a character class meant to match sequences of chars. You need to add an alternative to this regex that will match char sequences.

To remove any punctuation other than a certain list of smileys you may use

```
re.sub(r"(:-?[()D])|[^A-Za-z0-9\s]", r"\1" , s)
```

Or, in Python 3.4 and older, due to [the `re.sub` bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35516425/3832970):

```
re.sub(r"(:-?[()D])|[^A-Za-z0-9,\s]", lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else "", s)
```

If you really need to avoid removing commas, add `,` into the negated character class:

```
re.sub(r"(:-?[()D])|[^A-Za-z0-9,\s]", r"\1" , s)
                               ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nDN665/1).

**Details**

- `(:-?[()D])` - matches and captures into Group 1 a `:`, then an optional `-`, and then a single char from the character class: `(`, `)` or `D` (this captures the smileys like `:-)`, `:-(`, `:)`, `:(`, `:-D`, `:D`)
- `[^A-Za-z0-9,\s]` - matches any char but an ASCII letter, digit, comma and whitespace. To make it fully Unicode aware, replace with `(?:[^\w\s,]|_)`.

See the [Python 3.5+ demo](https://ideone.com/kjTKsR):

```
import re
s = "Hi, this is good :)#"
print( re.sub(r"(:-?[()D])|[^A-Za-z0-9,\s]", r"\1" , s) )
# => Hi, this is good :)
```

See [this Python 3.4- demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35516425/3832970):

```
import re
s = "Hi, this is good :)#"
print( re.sub(r"(:-?[()D])|[^A-Za-z0-9,\s]", lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else "", s) )
# => Hi, this is good :)
```

Comment: This is the perfect regex pattern it should recognize only the smileys rather than ")" and ":".Python2 throws an error while having this regex pattern.it will work only on python 3 ?

Comment: @noobster Yes, it won't work with any Python before Python 3.5 where the issue was fixed. Use https://rextester.com/VKR32235 with earlier versions.

Comment: @noobster Glad it works, please consider accepting the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

you can escape special characters with `\` try:

```
re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9:):D:\-))]+", " " , words)
```