# Removing parentheses around a date using regex

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a string like this:

> This is my (2019) awesome string (that I want to modify)

The date in it has to stay, but without parentheses. Meanwhile everything else that is in parentheses has to go. So I would like to achieve this:

> This is my 2019 awesome string

I am able to locate the date using this:

```
\b(201\d{1})\b
```

And I am also able to locate anything in parentheses using this:

```
(\(.*\))
```

But I only want to remove everything if it's not a date in parentheses or else I want to keep the date only removing the parentheses. Is there a way to do this without using `if else`?

Comment: By "date", do you mean just a year in the format 201X?

Comment: Yup, just year in format 201X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3.5+ you may use

```
s = re.sub(r'\((\d{4})\)|\([^()]*\)', r'\1', s)
```

If there is a `(` + 4 digits + `)`, only keep the 4 digits, else, remove the match.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iXENWE/2).

**Details**

- `\((\d{4})\)` - `(`, then Capturing group 1 matching four digits and then `)`
- `|` - or
- `\([^()]*\)`  - a `(`, then 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`, and then `)`.

The replacement is just `\1` backreference to the value of Group 1.

**NOTE**: To use this approach in Python versions before 3.5 you will have to use a lambda expression as the replacement argument (due to a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35516425/3832970)):

```
s = re.sub(r'\((\d{4})\)|\([^()]*\)', lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else '', s)
```

Comment: @Sweeper Right, for Python 3.5 and later versions, the backreference in the replacement pattern will work. However, with older versions, it will still require a lambda expression with `if else`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew out of curiosity, would it be possible to say, replace everything between parenthesis unless it contains 4 digits? Been trying with `re.sub('\(^(?:\d{4})\)','', s)` but no luck. Does `^` not work with non-capturing groups?

Comment: @yatu That is the first pattern I wrote when I saw this question :):  `re.sub(r'\((?!\d{4}\))[^()]*\)','', s)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LzWbfM/1).

Answer (score 0):

Just do it with two nested calls to `re.sub`:

```
re.sub(r' ?\(.*\)', '', re.sub(r'\((\d{4})\)', '\\1', my_string))
```

The inner regex looks for 4-digit numbers in parentheses and removes the parentheses. The outer one removes everything in parentheses that is left (including an optional space in the beginning).