# error "unmatched group" when using re.sub in Python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a list of strings. Each element represents a field as key value separated by space:

```
listA = [
'abcd1-2 4d4e',
'xyz0-1 551',
'foo 3ea',
'bar1 2bd',
'mc-mqisd0-2 77a'
]
```

#### Behavior

I need to return a `dict` out of this list with expanding the keys like `'xyz0-1'` by the range denoted by 0-1 into multiple keys like `abcd1` and `abcd2` with the same value like `4d4e`.

It should run as part of an Ansible plugin, where Python 2.7 is used.

#### Expected

The end result would look like the dict below:

```
{
abcd1: 4d4e,
abcd2: 4d4e,
xyz0: 551,
xyz1: 551,
foo: 3ea,
bar1: 2bd,
mc-mqisd0: 77a,
mc-mqisd1: 77a,
mc-mqisd2: 77a,
}
```

#### Code

I have created below function. It is working with Python 3.

```py
  def listFln(listA):
    import re
    fL = []
    for i in listA:
      aL = i.split()[0]
      bL = i.split()[1]
      comp = re.sub('^(.+?)(\d+-\d+)?$',r'\1',aL)
      cmpCountR = re.sub('^(.+?)(\d+-\d+)?$',r'\2',aL)
      if cmpCountR.strip():
        nStart = int(cmpCountR.split('-')[0])
        nEnd = int(cmpCountR.split('-')[1])
        for j in range(nStart,nEnd+1):
          fL.append(comp + str(j) + ' ' + bL)
      else:
        fL.append(i)

    return(dict([k.split() for k in fL]))
```

#### Error

In lower python versions like Python 2.7. this code throws an "unmatched group" error:

```
    cmpCountR = re.sub('^(.+?)(\d+-\d+)?$',r'\2',aL)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 275, in filter
    return sre_parse.expand_template(template, match)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 800, in expand_template
    raise error, "unmatched group"
```

Anything wrong with the regex here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Empty string instead of unmatched group error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516298/empty-string-instead-of-unmatched-group-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simpler version using `findall` instead of `sub`, successfully tested on 2,7. It also directly creates the dict instead of first building a list:

```
mylist=[
'abcd1-2 4d4e',
'xyz0-1 551',
'foo 3ea',
'bar1 2bd',
'mc-mqisd0-2 77a'
]

def listFln(listA):
    import re
    fL = {}
    for i in listA:
        aL = i.split()[0]
        bL = i.split()[1]
        comp = re.findall('^(.+?)(\d+-\d+)?$',aL)[0]
        if comp[1]:
            nStart = int(comp[1].split('-')[0])
            nEnd = int(comp[1].split('-')[1])
            for j in range(nStart,nEnd+1):
                fL[comp[0]+str(j)] = bL
        else:
            fL[comp[0]] = bL
    return fL
    
print(listFln(mylist))
# {'abcd1': '4d4e',
#  'abcd2': '4d4e',
#  'xyz0': '551',
#  'xyz1': '551',
#  'foo': '3ea',
#  'bar1': '2bd',
#  'mc-mqisd0': '77a',
#  'mc-mqisd1': '77a',
#  'mc-mqisd2': '77a'}
```

Comment: Good simplifying improvements: instead of replacing with `sub` and then extracting, the`findall` extracts any found groups at once.

Comment: Thanks; you, in turn, did a good job shedding light on the error OP encountered.

Answer (score 2):

Used Python **2.7** to reproduce. This answer shows the issue with not found backreferences for `re.sub` in Python 2.7 and some patterns to fix.

#### Both patterns compile

```py
import re

# both seem identical
regex1 = '^(.+?)(\d+-\d+)?$'
regex2 = '^(.+?)(\d+-\d+)?$'

# also the compiled pattern is identical, see hash
re.compile(regex1)  # <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7f575ef8fd40>
re.compile(regex2)  # <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7f575ef8fd40>
```

Note: The **compiled pattern** using [`re.compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) saves time when re-using multiple times like in this loop.

#### Fix: test for groups found

The error-message indicates that there are groups that aren't matched.
Put it other: In the matching result of [`re.sub` (docs to 2.7)](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.sub) there are references to groups like the second capturing group (`\2`) that have not been found or captured in the given string input:

> sre_constants.error: unmatched group

To fix this, we should test on groups that were found in the match.
Therefore we use `re.match(regex, str)` or the *compiled variant* `pattern.match(str)` to create a `Match` object, then [`Match.groups()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups) to return all found groups as tuple.

```py
import re

regex = '^(.+?)(\d+-\d+)?$'  # a key followed by optional digits-range
pattern = re.compile(regex)  # <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7f575ef8fd40>


def dict_with_expanded_digits(fields_list):
    entry_list = []
    for fields in fields_list:
        (key_digits_range, value) = fields.split()  # a pair of ('key0-1', 'value') 

        # test for match and groups found
        match = pattern.match(key_digits_range)
        print("DEBUG: groups:", match.groups())  # tuple containing all the subgroups of the match,
        # watch: the 3rd iteration has only group(1), while group(2) is None
        
        # break to next iteration here, if not maching pattern
        if not match:
            print('ERROR: no valid key! Will not add to dict.', fields)
            continue

        # if no  2nd group, only a single key,value
        if not match.group(2):
            print('WARN: key without range! Will add as single entry:', fields)
            entry_list.append( (key_digits_range, value) )
            continue  # stop iteration here and continue with next
            
        key = pattern.sub(r'\1', key_digits_range)
        index_range = pattern.sub(r'\2', key_digits_range)
        
        # no strip needed here
        (start, end) = index_range.split('-')
        for index in range(int(start), int(end)+1):
            expanded_key = "{}{}".format(key, index)
            entry = (expanded_key, value)  # use tuple for each field entry (key, value)
            entry_list.append(entry)

    return dict([e for e in entry_list])


list_a = [
  'abcd1-2 4d4e',  # 2 entries
  'xyz0-1 551',   # 2 entries
  'foo 3ea',  # 1 entry
  'bar1 2bd',   # 1 entry
  'mc-mqisd0-2 77a'  # 3 entries
]

dict_a = dict_with_expanded_digits(list_a)
print("INFO: resulting dict with length: ", len(dict_a), dict_a)

assert len(dict_a) == 9
```

Prints:

```
('DEBUG: groups:', ('abcd', '1-2'))
('DEBUG: groups:', ('xyz', '0-1'))
('DEBUG: groups:', ('foo', None))
('WARN: key without range! Will add as single entry:', 'foo 3ea')
('DEBUG: groups:', ('bar1', None))
('WARN: key without range! Will add as single entry:', 'bar1 2bd')
('DEBUG: groups:', ('mc-mqisd', '0-2'))
('INFO: resulting dict with length: ', 9, {'bar1': '2bd', 'foo': '3ea', 'mc-mqisd2': '77a', 'mc-mqisd0': '77a', 'mc-mqisd1': '77a', 'xyz1': '551', 'xyz0': '551', 'abcd1': '4d4e', 'abcd2': '4d4e'})
```

#### Note on added improvements

- renamed function and variables to express intend
- used tuples where possible, e.g. assignment `(start, end)`
- instead of `re.` methods used the equivalent methods of compiled pattern `pattern.`
- the guard-statement `if not match.group(2):` avoids expanding the field and just adds the key-value as is
- added `assert` to verify given list of 7 is expanded to dict of 9 as expected

Comment: Thank you @hc_dev. This one worked however I had to make slight changes to get 'foo' and 'bar1' in to the dict.

Comment: @Vijesh Thanks for your feedback. Glad to hear, that you tried the solution and adapted it to get expected 9 entries. I have also updated my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a single pattern with 4 capture groups, and check if the 3rd capture group value is not empty.

```
^(\S*?)(?:(\d+)-(\d+))?\s+(.*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\S*?)` Capture **group 1**, match optional non whitespace chars, as few as possible
- `(?:(\d+)-(\d+))?` Optionally capture 1+ digits in **group 2** and **group 3** with a `-` in between
- `(.*)` Capture **group 4**, match the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HCeLbM/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5SetxT)

Code example (works on Python 2 and Python 3)

```
import re

strings = [
    'abcd1-2 4d4e',
    'xyz0-1 551',
    'foo 3ea',
    'bar1 2bd',
    'mc-mqisd0-2 77a'
]

def listFln(listA):
    dct = {}
    for s in listA:
        lst = sum(re.findall(r"^(\S*?)(?:(\d+)-(\d+))?\s+(.*)", s), ())
        if lst and lst[2]:
            for i in range(int(lst[1]), int(lst[2]) + 1):
                dct[lst[0] + str(i)] = lst[3]
        else:
            dct[lst[0]] = lst[3]
    return dct


print(listFln(strings))
```

Output

```
{
    'abcd1': '4d4e',
    'abcd2': '4d4e',
    'xyz0': '551',
    'xyz1': '551',
    'foo': '3ea',
    'bar1': '2bd',
    'mc-mqisd0': '77a',
    'mc-mqisd1': '77a',
    'mc-mqisd2': '77a'
}
```

Comment: The element ```'foo 3ea'``` is not getting captured here.

Comment: @Vijesh I see, you are right. I have updated the answer.