# Using regex to remove comments from source files but keep some special comment

Tags: python, regex

I am programming the python code for removing the comments from source code too. But I want to keep the title of source code like

```
//**********************************
//*author
//*Function
//**********************************
```

and

```
//example
```

just remove // example (if there are blank after //).

I refer to this code， the highest score.

[Using regex to remove comments from source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319019/using-regex-to-remove-comments-from-source-files)

```
def remove_comments(string):
    pattern = r"(\".*?\"|\'.*?\')|(/\*.*?\*/|//[^\r\n]*$)"
    # first group captures quoted strings (double or single)
    # second group captures comments (//single-line or /* multi-line */)
    regex = re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
    def _replacer(match):
        # if the 2nd group (capturing comments) is not None,
        # it means we have captured a non-quoted (real) comment string.
        if match.group(2) is not None:
            return "" # so we will return empty to remove the comment
        else: # otherwise, we will return the 1st group
            return match.group(1) # captured quoted-string
    return regex.sub(_replacer, string)
```

I change a little for

`pattern = r"(\".*?\"|\'.*?\')|(/\*.*?\*/|//(?!(\*|\w))[^\r\n]*$)"`

It did not work for //*.

But I change * to # like

`pattern = r"(\".*?\"|\'.*?\')|(/\*.*?\*/|//(?!(#|\w))[^\r\n]*$)"`

```
//##################################
//#author
//#Function
//##################################
```

It work.

I just confuse what's difference between # and *? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What language is the source code written in?

Comment: I'm guessing the important part is the `//` which marks the line as a comment.  Following it with `*` or `#` has no meaning... since it is a comment, anything following the initial `//` is ignored.

Comment: Are you are that the asterix `*` is a special character when composing a regex?  It is a wildcard.  So, if you want to match the `*` you need to escape it, like this `\*`.  The `#` is not special, and does not need to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks for every one’s help. I use python. Yes， you are right, the reason is //. I changed my pattern to  pattern = r"(\".*?\"|\'.*?\')|((?<!/)/\*.*?\*/|//(?!(\*|\w))[^\r\n]*$)"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a string of

```
#The \n would be the linebreaks to hold multiple lines in a single string
string = '/**********************************\n//*author\n//*Function\n//*********************************\n//example\n// example'
```

and that you want to only remove `//example` and not anything within encompassing blocks, you can do

```
regex = re.compile(r'^(\/{1,2})(?![\*\s\/]{1,}).*$', re.MULTILINE)
re.sub(regex, "", string)

#output
'/**********************************\n//*author\n//*Function\n//*********************************\n\n// example'
```

There is still the `\n` remaining where the text used to be. Although keep in mind that something like `///example` would not be removed.